# DDD How to populate AggregateRoot from Repository when properties and collections should be readonly

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository, business-logic

If the entity should be always in valid state (therefore the properties are readonly and can be set only by methods which contains validation), How can I build this entity inside Repository without executing validations, because I suppose that database state is always valid ? Or should i always excecute validations even if the data source is database ?

For example i have this AggregateEntity Customer

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; private set; }
        public string ContactEmailHeadOffice { get; private set; }

        private List<Office> _offices = new List<Office>();
        public IEnumerable<Office> Offices => _offices.AsReadOnly();

        public void AddOffice(Office office, IRemoteDatabaseRepository repository)
        {
            office.Validate(); // May throw BusinessRuleException.

            if (!repository.DoRegistrationTokenExistForThisCustomer(Id, office.RegistrationToken))
            {
                throw new BusinessRuleException($"Registration token {office.RegistrationToken} does not exist for customer id {Id}.");
            };

        }
    }
```

But what is recommended way of populating the properties includes `_offices` collection ?

What should `CustomerRepository.Retrieve(int customerId)` contains ?

I want to avoid unnecessary validation and I want to be able to set the entity properties for the purpose of unit testing and also be able to get populated entity from the database.

Comment: Should an entity always be in a valid state? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372338/zero-argument-constructors-and-always-valid-entities/372488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove validation from the constructor, make the constructor internal, and call it from the repository to allow unvalidated object creation. If the repository is in a separate assembly, use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Next add a public static factory method to perform validation before returning a new object.

The internal constructor is also convenient for unit testing.

Another bonus is that a the static factory method can return some form of ValidationResult object instead of throwing exceptions.

Comment: this is great, thank you i will try it :)

Comment: it is really working ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [backing fields](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field) which allows entity framework to set private field directly.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Customer configuration.
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer", schema: "dbo").HasKey(x => x.Id);
            // Allow EF to access private collection field.
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Offices)
                .WithOne()
                .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Office>().ToTable("Office", schema: "dbo").HasKey(x => x.Id);
        }
```

so I can call (otherwise without backing field, read only exception is thrown)

```
Customer customer = _context.Customers.Where(x => x.Id == customerId).Include("Offices").FirstOrDefault();
```