# Where to execute domain validation which is not part of domain object?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm not sure where to place the following checks I have now in the material domain class. The issue is, that I need to validate that material exists and is valid in external database. Only after that validation I can be sure that I can use this material in our new project and store it in database. The Material object is part of collection in Order aggregate object. This is simplified example to demonstrate the issue.

**Material class**

```
  public class Material
        {
            public int? Id { get; private set; }
            public int RequestId { get; private set; }
            public int MaterialNumber { get; private set; }
            public int Quantity { get; private set; }

            // EF
            private Material()
            {
            }

            public Material(int requestId, int materialNumber, int quantity,
                string materialType, string materialStatus, string materialCondition)
            {
                if (materialCondition != "ZPR0")
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Material condition is not valid.");
                }

                if (materialType != "FERT" || materialType != "UNBW")
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Material type is not valid.");
                }

                if (materialStatus != "Z2" || materialStatus != "Z3" || materialStatus != "Z4")
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Material status is not valid.");
                }

                Id = requestId;
                MaterialNumber = materialNumber;
                Quantity = quantity;
            }
        }
```

**Order class**

```
public class Order : IAggregate
    {
        public int? Id { get; private set; }

        public IList<Material> Materials { get; }

        // EF
        private Order()
        {
        }

        public AddMaterial(Material material)
        {
            Materials.Add(material);
        }
}
```

Should I load materialType, materialStatus and materialCondition values from the database and pass it into domain entity inside Application layer (API) ? Or should I call some domain service (or repository method inside application layer) or domain validator to call some method IsMaterialValid(materialType, materialStatus and materialCondition) and after that materialize the Material object ? Its simple issue but I dont know how to handle it properly.

- I am not sure if this type of validation should be part of the domain object or not. And if not, is it possible to place it inside application layer or is it better to incorporate some domain service somehow ?
- The solution which I lean, is to create IsMaterialValid(int number) as database procedure and call it from repository in application layer, after that validation, create material object and pass it to Order object. It seems like most direct and easy way. What I don't like is that I will outsource the domain validation into database procedure (but as a plus I will still be dependent on validation method defined in repository interface).

Any idea ?

Comment: Not sure which language you are working with, but a more narrow exception would be appropriate.  `InvalidOperationException` suggests that the function is not available--or at least not in a state where it can take calls.  A `ValidationException` or `InvalidParameterException` might be more informative.

Comment: Thank you Berin, its C# I use this exception as a default exception for all the business exceptions.

Comment: It really does matter where you intend to do the validation.  If the validation is static (i.e. does not depend on data), then there is no problem with it in your domain object.  However, if you need to check the database first, I'd recommend putting that validation inside the repository.  That way your MaterialRepository can check for the existence of the requested material attributes either as a separate method, or as part of the save function.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the meaning of the "Detail" method. What business function is it modeling? A "detail" is usually a noun - a person, place or thing. Are you using it as a verb, as in "to detail a car"?

Comment: I'm also not sure what `materialCondition`, `materialStatus` and `materialCondition` have to do this any particular instance of Material. They are arguments passed in to the "Detail" method that constrain the values of properties on Matrial. Why are those three arguments not members of Material? Is this partial code?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Hello, you are right, it was a mistake, Detail method should be Material, I fixed it in the question.The material Condition, Status and Type attributes are not part of the domain entity, because I don't need them to be stored in the object, the purpose of these attributes its only to check, if the Material is valid and can be used for my business process (domain scope) but I don't use them anywhere else, therefore I dont store them inside the class as fields/properties.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Thank you, I did it just like you said, I placed the validation into Repository method, which calls database stored procedure (which loads external data and tell me if I can use this material for my business process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we discuss the proper way to model your problem, we need to remind ourselves that DDD is about focusing on the *behavior* our system is to exhibit. Unfortunately your question above takes a very data-centric perspective, and as a result makes synthesizing a solution more difficult for all parties involved. That is, it is still unclear to me *what* you are trying to do (other than avoid an exception). Of course I can glean that you don't want a `Material` added to an `Order` if it doesn't meet some criteria, but you never actually, specifically, denote that. I know what your thinking, "I have so!". Let me explain.

There are two ways to model this problem according to DDD. The first option asks us to determine what we are trying to *do* and incorporate the business rules *in* that process  (this is where my first point above is relevant). If we are following DDD and modeling the behavior of our system, then we should be modeling our business rules with that behavior. So if our behavior is "we can only `Add` a `Material` to an `Order` if it meets certain criteria", it would then follow that the logic to enforce our invariant should be placed in our `Order.AddMaterial` method! Option 1 is to refactor the aforementioned method to something like:

```
AddMaterial(Material material, int reqId, int qty, string type, string status, string 
         condition)
```

Or possibly (if we want to prevent the caller from holding a reference):

```
AddMaterial(int num, int reqId, int qty, string type, string status, string condition)
```

and place all of the those checks **in this method**. This makes sense right? It isn't the *construction* of a `Material` that needs extra checks. Rather, we only need to make sure a `Material` meets our requirement *when* it is to be added to an `Order`.

As an aside, an object's constructor should almost never contain business rules (there are exceptions for certain kinds of value objects where the object itself represents an abstraction with well-known, verifiable, semantics. e.g. `EmailAddress` ). It is data-centric thinking that leads to a failure to properly model, and often even *understand*, behavior. This usually manifests in the creation of abominations for constructors.

The second option is to move this logic into a `Repository`. Importantly, **not** in the way you have described! There is no such thing as (public) `isValid`-type methods when following DDD. Again, this is because it starts to move our focus away from the behavior of our system, and instead towards the data. A more DDD-centric approach is to model this invariant as a query that could return nothing (or throw):

```
// Order Command Handler

// throws if not found (respecting invariants)
var material = materials.Find(cmd.materialNumber);

order.AddMaterial(material, cmd.requestId, cmd.quantity);
```

In this way we are able to both leverage our database to help with validation and also keep our focus on the behavior of our system. That is, we keep validation "under the hood".

**Note**: There are suitable variations of the above approaches for differing "slices"/definitions of `Material`. The versions I have chosen in my examples above are actually distinct from one another and are both different from the version you give above. It may be more instructive if I named your version `MaterialItem`, my version for option 1 simply `Material`, and my version for option 2 `OrderMaterial`.

This is because your version seems to include semantics that only the `Order` would care about (e.g. `quantity`), my option 1 version represents only the thing itself (combined with `Order` semantics when added), and my option 2 is a version that does not include `Order` semantics but *does* represent a material that is suitable to be added to an `Order`.

What I am saying is that the differing contexts (read: behaviors) within which we are operating affect how we understand our model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, placing validation into Order make sense but the validation for the material number is common for the whole domain context, so I don't think it's necessary to add the validation to the Order. In my case I believe it is not directly the Orders responsibility. So therefore I like your second option where you hide the validation in the material repository.

Comment: When I am thinking about it again, my object naming is confusing, becase Material is not really a material, but more likely an OrderItem which contains an identifier of material which I want to validate. But anyway, in application service I need to use that `var material = materials.Find(cmd.materialNumber);` to receive a material and not create it directly via constructor, otherwise it will evade the validation which is very similar as using `materials.IsMaterialNumberValid(cmd.materialNumber);` only naming convention is different.

Comment: What I dont understand is why constructor should almost never contains business rules ? I need to ensure, that domain entity is always valid, even when created.

Comment: @Muflix Coincidentally I already have an answer to this one: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372338/zero-argument-constructors-and-always-valid-entities/372488#372488

Comment: Good answer @king-side-slide, I agree with the example that validations such as
"Customer must be over 18 to register",
"Customer must be under 25 to qualify for discount on registration",
"Customer must be over 25 to make reservation"
should be part of domain methods. But some general validations in constructor doesn't seem like a problem to me (based on my limited experience), in other way I can create some factory method for the object creation which is technical workaround with nicer name, if needed.

Comment: @Muflix My linked answer doesn't go into this topic as deeply as you are probing. There *are* certain kinds of validations that are usually appropriate in constructors. Importantly, these **are not** business rule-type validations, rather, technical validations (data-centric). There are two types of technical validations, those that are intrinsic to the data: `startDate` must be less than `endDate`, and those that are intrinsic to your system (usually DB constraints): string must be less than 100 chars.

Comment: @Muflix It's easy enough for me to exemplify, in your own system, why you don't want your validation in a constructor. Imagine you keep the checks in your `Material` ctor. Now some time later you need to add an additional invalid `materialType`. Easy enough. Add it to the check! Now answer me this: What happens when you try to load a past `Order` (and it's `Material` collection) from your database where that `Order` had this, now invalid, `materialType`?

Comment: @Muflix The danger with putting business rules in a non-business context is that business rules *change*. Had we kept our rule in its business context (the `AddMaterial` method) there would be no regression. Conversely, there is no danger applying data-centric rules (`startDate` is *always*, in any context, less than `endDate`). Does that make sense?

Comment: yes it makes sense, thank you for explanation. You are right about the validation change in the constructor for the historic data, because in my case entity framework always use empty constructor, so there is no validation when loading data from the data store. It means that historical data that is no longer valid according to the new rules in the constructor can still be loaded, thanks to an empty constructor.